# LEGO Digital Designer is unable to connect to the Internet

Tags: software, ldd

I just installed LEGO Digital Designer on my Macbook Pro running OS X (10.8.2).  Every time I start up the application, it immediately displays a dialog box stating "Internet access failed" as you can see below. Clicking retry does not help as it simply pops up the same dialog box again, clicking cancel shuts the program down.  Clicking ok simply allows the program to run in offline mode which is not what I want.

[image]

I have tried disabling the firewall on my computer, but that did not resolve the issue.  I do not have an antivirus program running that would block the application and all of the other programs on my computer access the internet just fine which leads me to believe that there may be something wrong with the application.

I did some research and couldn't find a definitive solution for this issue.  One proposed solution is to disable parental controls, but I don't have it enabled on my computer.

Have any of you come across this issue and come up with a resolution?

Comment: I saw this same problem yesterday, but at some point during the day it stopped happening, and I haven't seen it again. Perhaps a problem on the server end?

Comment: Checked the application this evening and the issue is no longer occurring.  It must have been an issue with their servers because I hadn't changed anything on my router or computer since I created this posting.  In fact, I contacted LEGO customer service and they instructed me to change some firewall settings, but I knew that wasn't the issue because my other Apple Computer was working just fine.  I am going to respond back to the LEGO customer service email and inform them that their error handling should be more informative, especially if it an issue with their servers.